Error al dar permisos de Escritura en Android 14 en Flutter
Estos son los permisos que tengo en mi proyecto de flutter para hacer la insercion de datos en una base de datos sqflite




y los metodos donde llamo a la funcion y donde me aparece el error es el siguente:
Future _requestStoragePermission() async {
PermissionStatus status = await Permission.storage.status;
if (!status.isGranted) {
  status = await Permission.storage.request();
}

if (status.isGranted &&
    (await Permission.manageExternalStorage.isGranted ||
        await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request().isGranted)) {
  return true;
} else if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
  await openAppSettings();
  return false;
} else {
  return false;
}

}
void iniciarDescarga(BuildContext context) async {
bool isGranted = await _requestStoragePermission();
if (isGranted) {
  setState(() {
    mostrarListaDescargas = true;
  });
  fetchAndSaveData();
} else {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Text(
          'El permiso de almacenamiento es necesario para descargar los datos.'),
    ),
  );
}

}

los permisos en el manifest: 



